# Scrollbar blinks on overflow change

Tags: css

I am using Chrome for emulating iPhone 6 and am using Developer tools.

I have a container which scrolls.

When container has `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` scrollbar is by default hidden and only appears when actually scrolling. This is the desired behavior.

But when the overflow is hidden and then in Developer tools I change from `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:auto` the scrollbar blinks (i.e it shows for a second and than disappears).

I don't want that blinking when overflow changes. I want the scrollbar to always remain invisible (until scrolling actually happens).

I'm hoping for a simple CSS property I can change to remove the blinking.

**EDIT:**

The app is designed for all browsers and devices, and I've tested it on actual android phone and there behavior is the same.

Above explanation is the simplest case you can test. The actual story is like this:
The container has overflow-x:auto, and the blinking appears when the page is loaded, where it actually bothers me.

As for the code, I think this would be enough to reproduce:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="contents"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  display:block;
}
#contents{
  position:relative;
  width:1000px;
  height:1000px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

So contents are bigger than smartphone screen (and container) wich triggers overflow. X or Y overflow it doesn't matter, let's say it's overflow-x.

Comment: can you share you code to have more info what you are doing ...

Comment: I removed those tags because they are useless in this case.

Comment: `I am using Chrome for emulating iPhone 6 and am using Developer tools.` This seems to be the problem. Emulation is not the same than test in an iPhone, trust me, I've been using it for years. You are seeing a scrollbar that in iOS you don't, or at least not the same behaviour. I suggest to you to get a real iPhone 6 and test it. There are javascript and css differences between the emulator and the real iOS, you can get a surprise when you test all in a real iPhone if you don't made it before.

Comment: Agree with @Marcos, the emulation mode does probably not reflect how a real device would behave. I suggest you use a service such as browserstack to verify whether the problem does actually exist on a real device first of all.

Comment: updated the question